# What is an example of a weakly universal hash function that is not pairwise independent?

Tags: hash, hash-tables, probabilistic-algorithms

A family of hash functions $H_w$ is said to be *weakly universal* if for all $x \ne y$ :

$$P_{h \in H_w}(h(x) = h(y)) \leq 1/m$$

Here the function $h:U \rightarrow [m]$ is chosen uniformly from the family $H$ and we assume $|U| > m$.

A family of hash functions $H_s$ is said to be *strongly universal* if for all $x \ne y$ and $k, \ell \in [m]$:

$$P_{h \in H_s}(h(x) = k \land h(y) = \ell) = 1/m^2$$

What is a concrete example of a hash function family which is weakly universal but not strongly universal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $U = [m]$, and let $h$ be the identity function.

If you insist that $|U| > m$, then you can take $U = [m+1]$, and consider the functions $h_i$, for $i \in [m]$, given by
$$
h_i(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \neq m+1, \\
i & \text{if } x = m+1.
\end{cases}
$$
The same approach can be used for arbitrary $|U|$: fix the first $m$ coordinates, and make all other coordinates uniformly and independently random.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant $|U|$ to be larger than $m$? Let me fix that.

Comment: Is there anything else you forgot about the question? I don't like continuously changing my answer to fit an ever-changing question.

Comment: No I don’t think so.  Thank you for your very nice answer to the first version.

Comment: See if you like the new answer...

Comment: Thank you. With your additional comment this is perfect. It does make you wonder why this is not taught in algorithms classes.

Comment: Well, it makes a nice exercise.

Comment: Actually I am confused. How can we map all other elements of the universe uniformly and independently in practice? It feels like you would need to store a vast lookup table. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I don’t see any lookup tables in your question. Perhaps you need to spend more time formulating your question. When you have a concrete follow-up question, you can ask it separately.